# PHP Variables how to

Tags: php, variables

I can't figure out how to use PHP variables

```
if( $xml = file_get_contents( $user '/docs.xml') ) {
```

It says unexpected `''/docs.xml'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)`

I've researched and can't find anything on adding variables to `get_file_contents`

*Please Help*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably quoting issue, so try this:

```
if( $xml = file_get_contents("$user/docs.xml") ) {
```

Comment: "Probably"? The question has invalid syntax, yours is (one version of) the correct syntax. You're not wrong, but have some confidence in your answer!

Comment: Thanks, I guess I've convinced myself not to trust me :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to combine the variable and the string literal via [concatenation](http://www.php.net/manual/language.operators.string.php) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation)):

```
if( $xml = file_get_contents( $user . '/docs.xml') ) {
```

Also, if you use [double quoted strings](http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double), you can place the variable inside of the string and have its value expanded:

```
if( $xml = file_get_contents("$user/docs.xml") ) {
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if ($xml = file_get_contents( $user . '/docs.xml') ) {
}
```

Looks like you are trying to concatenate, or combine the $user variable with the literal string '/docs.xml'.

In PHP you combine strings with the period . operator.

```
$string = "Testing" . " to see" . " if this really works";
echo $string;
// Outputs: Testing to see if this really works.
```

Comment: There is no comma operator in PHP. You may be thinking of the `echo` statement, which can take multiple arguments separated with commas.

Comment: Thank you IMSoP that is what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to concatenate strings in PHP. You should try this.

```
if( $xml = file_get_contents( $user . "/docs.xml") ) {
```

Read more on [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).